# Why doesn't my text block style get applied?

Tags: wpf, listview, styles, textblock

I have a style created in my windows resources area:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
</Style>
```

I thought this meant that all text blocks would have this style, so when I create my list view column:

```
<GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Source"/>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source, Mode=OneWay}" />
         </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

The ellipsis style is NOT applied to the text block in the column.

If I name the style with x:Key, then use Style={StaticResource xxx} then it works - why doesn't the unnamed approach work?

Here's the complete window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewStyle.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Source"/>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Primary"/>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Primary, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Secondary"/>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Secondary, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
</Window>
```

Comment: I know that this is an old question, but today the exact same question was asked and your question was linked there. I provided an answer there, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385905/why-doesnt-my-style-get-applied/40388383#40388383

Answer (score 0):

You may be defining another `TextBlock` style, closer to the `TextBlock` itself.

The way WPF searches for a style starts with the item to be styled. If it sets the `Style` property, then it uses that. Otherwise, it checks the parent's resources, then its grandparent's resources, and so on, using the first style it finds. If it doesn't find a style in your application it uses the default style.

There is probably a `TextBlock` style in one of the `TextBlock`'s ancestors. If it finds a style there, it won't use the one at the window level.

You can specify that one style is based on another, with the [`BasedOn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx) property.

Comment: There's only one style for text blocks and that's in the window resources.

Comment: Hmm, maybe there is one defined behind the scenes somewhere. I can't think of any other reason.