# Why doesn't my style get applied?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, styles

my question is the same as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231095/why-doesnt-my-text-block-style-get-applied). But since this old post is without an answer for four years I thought maybe there are new insights on why this is not working like it's supposed to be.

In my window resources I define a simple style for a `TextBlock`. The style doesn't have a `x:Key` attribute, so it's supposed to be applied to all `TextBlock` controls within my window which doesn't have a style of their own.

Then I create a `ListView` with a `GridView` defined as its view. The `ListView` has four colums defined, two columns are defined with an explicit `CellTemplate` containing a `TextBlock` and two columns are defined without an explicit `CellTemplate`.

Here's my complete XAML-code (the question follows under the code):

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Bottom" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bottom}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Left" Width="50">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Left}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Right" Width="50">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Right}" TextAlignment="Right" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Top" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Top}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.Items>
        <Thickness>1,2,3,4</Thickness>
        <Thickness>5,6,7,8</Thickness>
        <Thickness>9,10</Thickness>
    </ListView.Items>
</ListView>
</Window>
```

If I run this code, I can see, that my `TextBlock` style, that is supposed to be applied to all `TextBlock` controls, is only active in the columns that don't have an explicit `CellTemplate`.

Why is that?

When I inspect the visual tree I can see, that the working columns (the ones *without* a `CellTemplate`) are made of a `TextBlock` with my style applied to it, while the columns, which don't work (the ones *with* a `CellTemplate`) are made of a `ContentPresenter` with a `TextBlock` inside, but the `TextBlock` has no style at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is actually by design. [This link](http://www.11011.net/archives/000692.html) describes what is going on. There was also a bug report on Microsoft Connect back in October 2006. Unfortunately the original link to the bug report in the given link does not work anymore.

Here I'm reciting the answer to the bug report from Connect in case the given link goes down in future.

> This behavior is 'By Design' and this is why. Templates are viewed as an encapsulation boundary. Elements produced by these templates fall within this boundary. And lookup for a style with a matching TargetType stops at this boundary. Hence the TextBlock in the repro which is produced through a template does not pick up the Style in question. Whereas the TextBlock defined outside the template does.
>   One way to work around this problem is to give an explicit name to the Style and reference the style by this name on the TextBlock within the template.

You see that they already provided a workaround for your issue. They state that you should give your `TextBlock` style in the `Window.Resources` a name and reference the style in the template.

I think this is not what you actually want, because in that case the style doesn't automatically get applied to all TextBlocks (outside the DataTemplate). For that reason, instead of giving the style in `Windows.Resources` an explicit name, you can do a little trick in your `BasedOn` property when referencing the style. Instead of specifying the name of the style, you specify the type like this.

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Left" Width="50">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" />
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Left}" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

With that approach, you still have the advantage of not specifying a name for your style and the style gets applied to all TextBlocks.

For reference, the whole Window XAML looks like this. Now, all columns in the `GridView` have the same style.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="TextTrimming" Value="CharacterEllipsis" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Bottom" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bottom}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Left" Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" />
                            </DataTemplate.Resources>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Left}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Right" Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" />
                            </DataTemplate.Resources>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Right}" TextAlignment="Right" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Top" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Top}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.Items>
            <Thickness>1,2,3,4</Thickness>
            <Thickness>5,6,7,8</Thickness>
            <Thickness>9,10</Thickness>
        </ListView.Items>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations on that matter. I think I'll stick to the `x:Key` style and a style attribute at the `TextBlock`, that's more direct. And since I have to put it in every `DataTemplate` anyway...